Disk Not Ejected Properly – Eject [DISKNAME] before disconnecting or turning it off
Every few days I wake my MacBook from sleep to find a “Disk Not Ejected Properly – Eject DISKNAME before disconnecting or turning it off” notification from Finder.
When I call Apple, they say they can only help with problems that I have tested in Safe Boot Mode or with new users. I tell them that makes no sense, why would I enable Time Machine in either of those scenarios and wait days for the problem to recur.
I am running macOS 14.6.1. My drive is connected via USB. Time Machine runs hourly. Display turns off after 20 minutes. “Prevent automatic sleeping on power adapter when the display is off” is off. “Wake for network access” is “always”.

I use a NAS on my home network, and I get those notifications daily, sometimes more. It feels like a bug but maybe someone smarter than me knows why and/or has a fix

I get this with my Time Machine drive every couple of weeks or so.  (As well as the ‘Disk Not Ejected Properly’ warning, it also shows a dialog asking for the Time Machine password; but if I dismiss that, it remounts the drive anyway.)  — My best guess is some sort of USB issue: maybe a dodgy USB cable, or hub, or other USB device connected to it.  (My errors reduced significantly after replacing an old USB cable.)

I have noticed this happening on my M2 Mac Mini (macOS 14.6.1) with an external USB hard drive. I wonder if this was "introduced" in a recent update.


What model & year Mac is this? 2. What brand & model drive is this? 3. Through which cables / hubs / other devices is the drive attached to your Mac?


2021 MacBook Pro. Samsung Portable SSD T9. USB 3.1.

@2540625 It would be best to [edit] your post since comments can be deleted over time.

So, just to confirm, your Samsung T9 is connected directly via a USB-C cable to your Mac, with no intermediate adapters, hubs, devices, etc., between the two? Do you have any other devices attached to your Mac besides the SSD?

Confirmed. Only other connections would be two external displays/monitors/screens.

A couple of initial experiments to try: (1) Keep the system from sleeping for a full week (or longer, depending on the average time it takes to reproduce this issue) and see if the message stops occurring. (Make sure you’re plugged into AC, set “never” for the idle sleep timer in System Settings > Energy Saver, and also use the caffeinate command in Terminal). (2) If the problem reoccurs, try running for a week or more without either of your displays attached. (Other devices can trigger USB controller resets like the one you’re getting.) Please report back on your results!
